# Multi-page session, post all information to one table with AJAX involved

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm really new to PHP. I've been working on this multi-page form.

I have five pages, first page the user enters their email, second page is AJAX that posts to the same table, third page another $post using AJAX to add to the table, last page just destroys the session but echo's all the information and adds the data that was submitted. How would I be able to do that?

What my table looks like now, it only takes in the email but now the data:

email - data1 - data2 - data3

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to store the previous page's form in session data, slowly building up the entire form in session. On the last page, you just put it all into the table.

The only time you need AJAX is when you DON'T want to the page to refresh... If you have 5 pages, one leading to the other, you can just store all the values into the session, no AJAX needed.

Comment: Thanks, but in the second page, it's in jquery, there is a countdown timer and when they click "Finish" it goes to the next page - I only thought about using ajax because it post to the database. I guess i'm doing it wrong. Do you know a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can save data that user enters in the first and second page in the session, in the third page, output those saved data in hidden input fields or other hidden elements you preferred. and post all of those data including data 3 using AJAX POST.